# How can I make a changing numerical value for a taskbar icon in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

I'm trying to make a program in C# that monitors the processor time of an application. I'd like to have a feature in this program where the task-bar icon is actually a number representing the processor time (like what coretemp has). How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

Create a `Bitmap`, use `Graphics.FromImage` to draw on it, then call `Icon.FromHandle(myBitmap.GetHicon())`.
You can then set the icon as your form's `Icon` property.

**EDIT**: Like this:

```
using (var image = new Bitmap(16, 16)) 
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
    g.DrawString(...);
    myForm.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(image.GetHicon());
}
```

You can run this in a timer to continually update the icon.

You can get the CPU usage like this:

```
int usage;
using (var cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")) {
    cpu.NextValue();            //First value is 0
    usage = cpu.NextValue();
}
```

Comment: Okay, so if I'm reading this right, I would do something like this:
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Graphics.FromImage(someImage));

Icon.fromHandle(b.getHIcon());

I guess my only concern now is how to get the image itself - is there any easy way to tell C# to transform the processor time value into an image to use? The way I'm seeing this, and correct me if I'm wrong, is that Graphics.FromImage() insinuates I have to make the number icons myself.

Thanks for all the help so far, though. (And sorry if the code above is hard to read, I'm not sure if I can insert code blocks into comments.)

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks so much, I really learned something about this today. :)